# How to send form-data POST request with the help HttpClient with just Key-Value parameters

Tags: c#, request, multipartform-data, dotnet-httpclient

How can I to send a **form-data POST** request with the help of HttpClient with just Key-Value parameters?

Here is my code of the method:

```
public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> MakePostAsync(string endpoint, string token, Dictionary<string, string> headers = null, KeyValuePair<string, string>[] parameters = null)
        {
            var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, endpoint);
            if (headers != null)
            {
                foreach (var header in headers)
                    request.Headers.Add(header.Key, header.Value);
            }
            request.Headers.Add("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data");
            var formaData = new MultipartFormDataContent();

            formaData.Add(new StringContent(token), "__RequestVerificationToken");
            formaData.Add(new StringContent("admin"), "Username");
            formaData.Add(new StringContent("1"), "Password");
            request.Content = formaData;


            HttpResponseMessage response = await Task.Run(() => client.SendAsync(request));
            return response;
        }
```

[The same request in the Postan on JavaScript, but it works](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BN6dV.png)

Comment: What response message do you get back ?

Comment: why *"HttpResponseMessage response = await Task.Run(() => client.SendAsync(request));"* and not *"HttpResponseMessage response = await client.SendAsync(request);"* ?

Comment: and, are you sure you're sending with multipart/form-data in postman? looks like postman is sending text/json ?

Comment: so.. There is a Content-Type of request "multipart/form-data; boundary=--------------------------939589509105609250428586"

Comment: @Andrew - you see that while using postman?

Comment: @yob yes, [Request Headers screen link](https://monosnap.com/file/vUCFowBaIb0KGjte4N36uuv8Qrtf8G)

Answer (score 2):

This problem was resolved with the help of RestSharp. I needed to get Set-Cookie header value from the response of this request. And I just added CookieContainer to the RestClient. Not sure how to manage this problem with HttpClient. 
Thanks everybody who was trying to help.

Comment: something like this: System.Net.CookieContainer usercookie = new CookieContainer();
            var httpClient =  new System.Net.Http.HttpClient(new System.Net.Http.HttpClientHandler { CookieContainer = usercookie });

Answer (score 0):

You are not awaiting correctly.

Try: `var response = await client.SendAsync(request);`

Comment: can you install a tool like fiddler and capture the http request going out?